# My __del__() may raise ResourceWarning. Can KeyboardInterrupt cause an unwanted warning?

Tags: python, finalizer, keyboardinterrupt, resource-cleanup

Take this example copied from `python-3.9.0/Lib/asyncore.py` -

```
class file_wrapper:
    # Here we override just enough to make a file
    # look like a socket for the purposes of asyncore.
    # The passed fd is automatically os.dup()'d

    def __init__(self, fd):
        self.fd = os.dup(fd)

    def __del__(self):
        if self.fd >= 0:
            warnings.warn("unclosed file %r" % self, ResourceWarning,
                          source=self)
        self.close()

    # ...

    def close(self):
        if self.fd < 0:
            return
        fd = self.fd
        self.fd = -1
        os.close(fd)

    # ...
```

The purpose of ResourceWarning, is to warn when your program has a bug that "leaks" a resource.  Let us try to write a program without any such bug:

```
def test():
    f = None
    try:
        f = file_wrapper(sys.stdin.fileno)
        os.write(self.f.fd, b'!')
    finally:
        if f:
            f.close()
```

In cpython, suppose a console interrupt occurs after the CALL_FUNCTION opcode and before the STORE_FAST opcode.

A `file_wrapper` object will exist (on the stack), but it will not be bound to the variable `f`.

Despite how careful our program is, will the interrupt trigger our ResourceWarning?

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(test)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              2 STORE_FAST               0 (f)

  3           4 SETUP_FINALLY           44 (to 50)

  4           6 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (file_wrapper)
              8 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (sys)
             10 LOAD_ATTR                2 (stdin)
             12 LOAD_ATTR                3 (fileno)
             14 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             16 STORE_FAST               0 (f)
...
```

Comment: KeyboardInterrupt breaks all kinds of stuff, not just this. A program that wants safety even in the presence of Ctrl-C interrupts almost always has to install its own signal handler.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, such warnings can happen.  There is nothing to stop KeyboardInterrupt being raised between `CALL_FUNCTION` and `STORE_FAST`.

See [Nathan's blog post](https://vorpus.org/blog/control-c-handling-in-python-and-trio/), starting at "there are some details that can sometimes make our Python code a little more robust to KeyboardInterrupt".  The relevant [Python code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d41bddd/Python/ceval.c#L1759) has been changed slightly since then, but it does not affect our case. The changes only fix certain limitations Nathan mentioned with his own ideas.

Equally, KeyboardInterrupt could also occur before the first line of `file_wrapper.__init__()`.  In this case, `file_wrapper.__del__()` will be called before `self.fd` is set.  `__del__()` will try to read `self.fd`, raising an AttributeError exception.  The python standard library does not attempt to prevent this.

KeyboardInterrupt is a useful hack for getting a backtrace from your single-threaded program.  Particularly since you cannot attach the python debugger after starting your program.  It is not a reliable tool for writing a program which can be interrupted.